# Snackbar preventing Recyclerview from updating its view?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-snackbar

This is a really bizarre bug I am encountering.

If I run my code like this (adding a new item to my recyclerview), it works and updates fine:

```
mListOfData.add(someNewItem);
mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mListOfData);
mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

But if I display a Snackbar telling the user an item has been added, suddenly the list doesn't update in real time unless I recreate the activity (rotating the screen, etc):

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.primary_coordinator_layout);
mListOfData.add(someNewItem);
mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mListOfData);
mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
Snackbar.make(view, "Item added!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Any reason why this may be or how to prevent it from blocking the visual update?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/primary_coordinator_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emptytext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/no_items_in_recyclerview"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to dismiss the `snackbar` afterward:

```
final RecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter2 = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mListOfData);


//create local snackbar
final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(view, "Item added!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

snackBar.setAction("Blah blah", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter2);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        snackBar.dismiss();
    }
}); 
snackBar.show();
```

Comment: Same problem unfortunately

Comment: I found out the reason, had nothing to do with the Snackbar (had to do with the visibility of the emptyview not being set correctly), but I'll give a checkmark/upvote for the time and effort

Comment: Cheers! Did you mention the empty view in the question?